# how to restore softwares in linux from an old hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, restore

I recently removed my old harddrive from my linux machine, as the linux was corrupted due to accidental deletion of /bin folder. I have inserted a new harddisk and installed a new linux system (which is newer version than the previous one), and have the old harddisk with me. My question is how do I restore important softwares and packages I had in my old harddrive to the new one? Any suggestions would be largely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on filesystem on your old HDD. Here is general plan:

1. Install restoring software on your new Linux system. The software choice depends on the filesystem;
2. Mount old HDD on your new Linux machine;
3. Restore files.

Not sure but as I know not all filesystems allow to restore deleted files. Here is an [example](https://www.tecmint.com/ext3grep-recover-deleted-files-on-ubuntu-debian/amp/) for ext3.
If you provide more details, possible you will have exact answer can you do what you want or not.